# How do I listen admob interstitial impressions?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, admob

I need to listen to admob interstitial, that if on success should fetch an image from my website. I can figure out the latter part., but I like to know how to listen to that event.
ie, the function should execute if an impression is created successfully.
I need to do this in flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to interstitial ad events with `_onInterstitialAdEvent`. Specifically for impression event there is a type of event `MobileAdEvent.impression`. You can call your function in that case.

```
void _onInterstitialAdEvent(MobileAdEvent event) {
    switch (event) {
      case MobileAdEvent.impression:
        //call your function here
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The same applies for rewarded video?

Comment: Not same, but similar. For rewarded video ads, the listener provides an event of type `RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded` which is when the user has watched the complete video ad and so can now be rewarded.